# Multiprocess web application using API or MessageQueue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm testing [multiprocessing](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) using [*apply_async*](https://multiprocess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiprocess.html#module-multiprocess.pool).
However, it looks like each *apply_async* is called from `MainProcess` and it's not exactly asynchronous. Each function is called only after previous one is finished. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

I'm using Windows with Python 3.8, so it's using the spawn method to create processes.

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count, current_process
from threading import current_thread


def go_to_sleep():
    pid = os.getpid()
    thread_name = current_thread().name
    process_name = current_process().name
    print(f"{pid} Process {process_name} and {thread_name} going to sleep")
    time.sleep(5)


def apply_async():
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    print(f"Number of procesess {len(pool._pool)}")
    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(go_to_sleep())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


def main():
    apply_async()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    main()
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Elapsed run time: {end_time - start_time} seconds.")
```

Output:

```
Number of procesess 8
26776 Process MainProcess and MainThread going to sleep
26776 Process MainProcess and MainThread going to sleep
26776 Process MainProcess and MainThread going to sleep
```

Comment: Are you sure? Perhaps you're only seeing buffered output. Can you put a timestamp on each? If indeed true, perhaps you need to wait for an event that the process is finished?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do and what output you expect. Please clarify.

Comment: Also note that according to docs,  the pool must be running before you can use *apply_sync*. Then it's also weird that you close the pool, just before joining it. Why are you doing that?

Comment: You are also missing a *get()* to actually get any results, but since you're not having any, I'm not sure how the process scheduler is handling just a bunch of wait states. So maybe you should have another look at the [*Pool* examples](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess/blob/master/py3.8/examples/ex_pool.py)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code is not actually calling the specified function in the process pool, it is calling it in the main thread, and passing the result of calling it to `pool.apply_async`.

That is, instead of calling `pool.apply_async(go_to_sleep())`, you should call `pool.apply_async(go_to_sleep)`.  You [need to pass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) the *function* that should be called to `Pool.apply_async` - you should not call the function when you call `Pool.apply_async`.